# android: ListActivity : setSelection: change color

Tags: android, listview

I am using ListView using ListActivity in my android app.

```
public class OutlineActivity extends ListActivity{
    

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.add("apple00");
        adapter.add("apple01");
        adapter.add("apple02");
        adapter.add("apple03");
        adapter.add("apple04");
        adapter.add("apple05");
        adapter.add("apple06");
        adapter.add("apple07");
        adapter.add("apple08");
        adapter.add("apple09");
        adapter.add("apple10");
        adapter.add("apple11");
        adapter.add("apple12");
        ...
        adapter.add("apple1100");
        
        setSelection(10);

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);

    }
}
```

The above code shows the list. I want to `setSelection(10);` to be highlighted with some color. How to do it.

I tried

```
getListView().getChildAt(getSelectedItemPosition()).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

This stops the program saying

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
```

how to do it.

Comment: Have you checked the logs for the error because of which the application crashes?

Comment: added the log why application crashes. in the question

Comment: It's a NPE, see you're setting the background color on a null object which means this `getListView().getChildAt(getSelectedItemPosition())` returns no object/child. First try to access the `getSelectedItemPosition()` to see whether it returns a position or not, if it does return a position, then there's no child at that position which means invalid position, if it doesn't means invalid position as well or no selected item.

Comment: use RecyclerView :)

Comment: Only reason i am using ListView is fastscroll is very easy to implement. In recyclerview its not  working well.